# I can't modify my profile

Tags: discussion, login

I get this weird messages whenever I try to modify my profile: "Oops! There was a problem updating your profile: This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account."

Of course I did what it says, three times. As I am logged in, I clicked the the recovery thing and changed my password, but even after that, when I try to modify mi profile picture, username or anything, it pops up de same message.

I tried the Help Center but it says nothing about that and there seems to be no way of asking directly to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can contact Stack Overflow directly by using this link. 
https://stackoverflow.com/contact